# Which container will be targeted when replicas larger than 1

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

Below is a simplified version of my `docker-compose.yml` file.

I can understand or find any resources to tell me which container of the 5 `django` replicas the nginx container will target if i reference it.

For example, as you can see if my compose file I have one instance of Nginx and five of Django.

If my nginx config i have an upstream like this:

```
upstream docking_django {
    server web:3000;
}
```

Which web container will the upstream come from? Will it load balance between them?
I'm deploying to AWS ECS and when I try running it, it seems like it's load balancing somehow. But I would like to understand it further since it doesn't seem to behave the same way always.

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    image: .dkr.ecr.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/tin-api-v2/django:${IMAGE_TAG}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    networks: 
      - demoapp
    deploy:
      replicas: 5

  nginx:
    image: .dkr.ecr.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/tin-api-v2/nginx:${IMAGE_TAG}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./nginx.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web
    networks: 
      - demoapp
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

networks:
  demoapp:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Felix. Loosely speaking it "load balance" across your 5 web container instances. If you are using the ECS / Compose integration and you are bringing up this stack with a `compose` up this is roughly what happens:

- it creates an ECS cluster
- it creates task def for the `web` task and the `nginx` task
- it creates a service for `web` (with 5 tasks in it)
- it creates a service for `nginx` (with 1 task in it)
- it exposes the `nginx` service via an ALB to the public (because you expose the port 80)
- it creates an internal mechanism based on ECS Service Discovery to be able to resolve `web` inside the cluster (that's how the `nginx` is able to reach an entity called `web`).

ECS SD leverages CloudMap/Route53 which will round-robin across the 5 entries (`web` tasks). You can read more [here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html).